# Global Networks - Are there any other than the Internet?

Tags: network

Here is the definition of Global Networks:

[image: Definition of Global Networks]

Currently does any Global Network exists (apart from Internet)? Can someone Quote some examples?

Doesn't every other WAN network comes under the category of "Enterprise Network"?

Comment: perhaps SIPRNET ?

Comment: Interesting question..

Comment: This isn't really a security question, and so is off-topic for the site, I'm afraid.

Comment: @GrahamHill - Also true, forgot this was the security SE.

Comment: Perhaps you make your criterias clearer, wikipedia gives a few examples of global networks (Mainlly mobile carriers and satelites)